# Clarification on using observeEvent and eventReactive together

Tags: r, shiny

I'm confused about reactivity, and I hope one of you guys can help.

When I used `eventReactive` in my code, I included a calculation involving variable `rpcMatrix` that doesn't get returned. (Instead, another variable, `DF_new`, gets returned.) I do admit this is a sloppy way of doing things, but I see no reason for it not to work.

Now, variable `RPC` is defined in `observeEvent` function. Although `RPC` isn't reactive, I believe its value does change in the `observeEvent` function as `wb` changes based on the `states()` reactive variable. When `RPC` changes, I hoped that the `eventReactive` function would cause `rpcMatrix` to change in the `for` loops.

Would `rpcMatrix` change based on changes in `RPC` if both variables are in `eventReactive`?

The reason why I avoided using the `reactive` keyword is because it was giving me trouble with assigning `wb` with the `loadWorkbook` command.
Thanks a lot for your help guys. I hope I made my question clear.

```
observeEvent(input$submit,{
   #NEXT 2 LINE ARE PERTINENT TO QUESTION: 

   wb <<- loadWorkbook(file =file.path(src,"www","State_Vectors",states()))
...
  RPC<<-read.xlsx(wb,sheet=1,startRow=1,cols=11)
})

data = eventReactive(input$submit,{
       ...
          DF_new<<- hot_to_r(input$tbl)

          *NEXT 2 LINES ARE PERTINENT TO QUESTION:
       rpcMatrix<<-as.data.frame(matrix(0, nrow= dim(as.matrix(category))[1], ncol =dim(as.matrix(category))[1]))
      for(i in 1:dim(category)[1]) #NTP
      {
        for(j in 1:dim(category)[1])
        {
          rpcMatrix[i,j]<<-as.matrix(RPC[i,1])
      }
      }
          DF_new<<-DF_new[,-c(1,2,6)] 
        }
       return(DF_new) 
        })
```

Comment: With  reactive or eventReactive you really don't need `<<-`

Answer (score 0):

This **cannot** be expected to work reliably. It is problematic because it requires a *specific order of execution* of two reactive statements triggered on the same `input$submit`. While there are some priority values that you might be able to set and thus get this to work more often, the priority functionality is unreliable and its use is highly discouraged.

But this "order of execution" problem is exactly what reactivity is designed to solve. I would suggest you consider working with `reactiveValues`.

They have two main features:

- **longevity across reactive invocation** As you are probably aware by now, the reactive functions have their own environments/scopes, and the variables you create there do not stick around. One workaround is using the `<<-` statement, but that is a "global variable" kind of approach and should be avoided in the functional world of R. It has a lot of issues. `reactiveValues` on the other are available in all the reactive scopes that you then create in your Shiny program. They are exactly what you need to avoid having to use that `<<-` statement to preserve state across invocations of your reactive code.
- **reactive effects** As an added benefit they cause the same sort of reactive effects that the `input$..` variables have. This is a very powerful feature and means you can create an entire reactive net of calculations - and you can use that here.

So I might recommend an approach like this:

```
rv <- reactiveValues(wb=NULL,RPC=NULL)

observeEvent(input$submit,{

   rv$wb <- loadWorkbook(file =file.path(src,"www","State_Vectors",states()))
   ...
   rv$RPC<-read.xlsx(rv$wb,sheet=1,startRow=1,cols=11)
})

data <- reactive({
      ...
      DF_new<- isolate(hot_to_r(input$tbl))

      rpcMatrix<-as.data.frame(matrix(0, nrow= dim(as.matrix(category))[1], 
                                         ncol =dim(as.matrix(category))[1]))
      for(i in 1:dim(category)[1]) #NTP
      {
        for(j in 1:dim(category)[1])
        {
          rpcMatrix[i,j]<-as.matrix(rv$RPC[i,1])
      }
    }
    DF_new<-DF_new[,-c(1,2,6)] 
  }
  return(DF_new) 
})
```

**It works like this:**

1. We set up a `reactiveValues` list named `rv` to hold `RPC`
2. Now when `input$submit` is triggered, the workbook will be loaded and `rv$RPC` will change.
3. Then the reactive `data` will be triggered (if used as `data()`) when `rv$RPC` changes.

Execution order is guarenteed, and this is what I think you want.

**Other notes:**

- I assume you don't want it to trigger when `input$tbl` changes, so I put that in an `isolate`. That is how `eventReactive` was treating it.
- It looks to me like you are calculating `DF_new` and `rpcMatrix` from scratch, thus you don't need to use the `<<-` operator for them (as HubertL mentioned in a comment).
- The exception would be if you wanted to use `DF_new` and `rpcMatrix` somewhere else, for example to display them for debugging or something. Then you could put then in `rv` as well, and address then in your `reactiveStatements` as `rv$DF_new` and `rv$rpcMatrix`.
- I am not sure if `wb` needs to be in that `reactiveValues` list or not, it could be you only need it locally in that `observeEvent`.

**Also in general with `reactiveValues` note**:

- outside of a reactive scope the elements in the `reactiveValues` can be accessed with `isolate(rv$NPC)`
- it is the elements that are reactive (like `rv$NPC` above), not the root (i.e. in the above `rv` is not reactive)
- One does not really need to initialize the variables in the `reactiveValues` statement with NULL, you can give them other initial values, or even leave them away and let them be created when they are used in an assignement. However I find it helps me to understand my program when I see them listed there.